# Advanced Auto Complete Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have created a simple autocomplete textfield (in which the autocomplete options are displayed in a tableview) through the following code:

```
import UIKit

class SchoolViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var schoolTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var autoCompleteTableView: UITableView!

    let schoolPossibilities = ["Redwood", "Fisher", "Bellermen", "Saratoga", "Los Gatos", "Cambell", "Mooreland", "Harker", "Challenger", "Saint Andrews", "Beckens", "Lynbrook", "Menlo", "Gunn", "Aragon", "Kipp"]
    var autoCompleteSchools = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        autoCompleteTableView.delegate = self
        schoolTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "someCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = autoCompleteSchools[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return autoCompleteSchools.count
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if let text = schoolTextField.text{
            let substring = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            searchAutoCompleteEntries(withSubstring: substring)
        }
        return true
    }

    func searchAutoCompleteEntries(withSubstring substring: String){
        autoCompleteSchools.removeAll()
        for key in schoolPossibilities{
            let string = key as NSString
            let range = string.range(of: substring)
            if range.location == 0{
                autoCompleteSchools.append(key)
            }
        }
        autoCompleteTableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

The problem is that options only show up if what's being typed in the textfield is an EXACT match. How do I change this code so it can tolerate both uppercase and lowercase letters and slight variations?

Comment: Pass the appropriate options to the `range(of:)` call. See the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSCaseInsensitiveSearch as compare option in

```
outputString.rangeOfString(String, options: NSStringCompareOptions, range: <#T##Range<Index>?#>, locale: <#T##NSLocale?#>)
```

Comment: What is the outputString referring to?

Comment: "outputString" is the string in which you want to perform check. In your case it is "string" (let string = key as NSString)